# SSH forwarding audio in Debian 12 KDE fails

Tags: linux, debian, ssh, audio, kde

(Several weeks ago, I posted this request-for-help on superuser.com, but didn't get any replies. Hence, I'm seeking help here.)

SYSTEMS:

1. X86_64 Debian 12 bookworm KDE AND Debian 11 bullseye KDE
2. Raspberry Pi 4B 8GB Raspberry Pi OS (64-bit) (official port of Debian Bookworm)

PROBLEM:

I have an X86_64 receiving audio from my Raspberry Pi via `ssh -X Bill@192.168.0.111 firefox https://www.youtube.com` (I'm just using firefox as an example here.)

Audio WORKS for this arrangement if Debian 11 (Bullseye) KDE is installed on the X86_64 receiving machine. Unfortunately, audio FAILS (no sound) if Debian 12 (Bookworm) KDE is installed on the X86_64 receiving machine.

WHAT I'VE TRIED:

I followed the setup instructions in: https://superuser.com/questions/231920/forwarding-audio-like-x-in-ssh (Equivalent to adding `load-module module-native-protocol-tcp` to `/etc/pulse/default.pa` on the X86_64 machine, then rebooting.) These instructions work for Debian 11 (Bullseye) KDE on the X86_64 machine, but fail for the Debian 12 (Bookworm) KDE X86_64 machine.

I understand that Debian 11 (Bullseye) KDE is using pulse-audio; while Debian 12 (Bookworm) KDE is using a hybrid of pulse-audio and pipewire. I've tried installing "wireplumber" and "pipewire-pulse" on the Debian 12 machine; but still failed to get audio forwarding from the Raspberry Pi to the X86_64 machine with Debian 12.

I would appreciate any guidance. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I think it is because of `pipewire` on Debian 12. Look into that, I'm pretty sure that's where the issue comes from. You might want to fully switch to `pulse-audio` on the `amd64` machine and give it a try.